# Update of field's "ShowInEditForm" in a content type is not being reflected

Tags: 2010, powershell, content-type, spfield

I'm trying to show a special field from a content type in the Edit Form of the Library `Invalids`. The field is called `Invalid`.

As far as, I can see in the PowerShell, the value of `ShowInEditForm` is set to `false`.

```
$site = Get-SPSite "http://testportal.xyz.de"
$web = $site.RootWeb
$lib = $web.Lists["Invalids"]
$ct = $lib.ContentTypes["Starting Point Formulations"]
$ct.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Invalid").ShowInEditForm
```

Result is `False`

Now when I update the field by using below PowerShell:

```
$ct.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Invalid").ShowInEditForm = $true
$ct.Update()
```

There is no error and the value is set to `True`. But, when I reload the content type again, the field's "ShowInEditForm" is showing `False`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: After updating content type, please try to update the library like $lib.Update() and dispose web object $web.Dispose().

Comment: @DivyaSharma Thanks for your help, but that did not work as well. It is really a strange issue.